# Building the prior, likelihood, and posterior in Bayesian linear regression in R using mtcars, tidy method

Tags: r, bayesian

I'm trying to understand something about how the prior distribution is combined with the likelihood to get the posterior distribution in Bayesian linear regression.

For context, I used `stan_glm()` against the `mtcars` dataset and got these parameter values for the `intercept` and `slope`: `37.3` and `-5.3`, respectively.

```
data(mtcars)
fit <- stan_glm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)

prior_summary(fit)
```

And here is the output.

```
stan_glm
 family:       gaussian [identity]
 formula:      mpg ~ wt
 observations: 32
 predictors:   2
------
            Median MAD_SD
(Intercept) 37.3    2.0  
wt          -5.3    0.6  

Auxiliary parameter(s):
      Median MAD_SD
sigma 3.1    0.4
```

Now I created a new dataframe, which I'm calling `new_cars_1990s`.

```
new_cars_1990s <- data.frame(
  car = c("Toyota Camry", "Honda Accord", "Ford Taurus", "Chevrolet Lumina", "Nissan Maxima", 
          "Mitsubishi Galant", "Subaru Legacy", "Volkswagen Passat", "Buick Regal", "Mercedes-Benz E-Class",
          "Acura Legend", "BMW 3 Series", "Lexus LS 400", "Ford Mustang", "Chevrolet Corvette", 
          "Mazda RX-7", "Toyota Supra", "Nissan 240SX", "Honda Prelude", "Volkswagen Golf",
          "Volvo 850", "Audi 100", "Mitsubishi Eclipse", "Pontiac Grand Am", "Ford Explorer",
          "Jeep Cherokee", "Toyota 4Runner", "Chevrolet Blazer", "GMC Jimmy", "Nissan Pathfinder"),
  wt = c(3.2, 2.9, 3.5, 3.8, 3.2, 3.1, 3.0, 3.2, 3.6, 3.9, 
         3.3, 3.0, 3.7, 3.5, 3.4, 2.8, 3.1, 3.2, 2.9, 2.8, 
         2.5, 3.4, 3.0, 2.7, 3.1, 4.0, 4.2, 3.8, 4.5, 4.3),  # Hypothetical weights in tons
  mpg = c(28, 30, 25, 23, 27, 26, 29, 28, 24, 22, 
          26, 28, 24, 18, 15, 19, 22, 21, 25, 26, 
          32, 23, 26, 28, 24, 17, 16, 18, 15, 16))
```

And I'm wondering if it's possible to build up the likelihood and the priors by myself, and then combine the likelihood and the priors to get two posterior distributions.

I know the approximate answer I'm looking for because I can use the `stan_glm()` function against the `new_cars_1990s` dataset and use the `prior_intercept` and `prior` arguments to set my prior. The posterior should be centered at `-5.6` for the `wt` coefficient and `43.6` for the `intercept`.

```
stan_glm(mpg ~ wt, data = new_cars_1990s,
  prior_intercept = normal(location = 37.3, scale = 2),
  prior = normal(location = -5.3, scale = 0.6))
stan_glm
 family:       gaussian [identity]
 formula:      mpg ~ wt
 observations: 30
 predictors:   2
------
            Median MAD_SD
(Intercept) 43.6    2.0  
wt          -5.6    0.6  

Auxiliary parameter(s):
      Median MAD_SD
sigma 3.7    0.6
```

Here is the part where I have a question and get lost. I create a regression using the parameters in my priors to predict `mpg`. And then I try to understand the likelihood of the predicted values given the distribution from my priors.

```
prior_sd_for_regression <- 3.1 
prior_slope <- -5.3
prior_sd_for_slope <- 0.8895613 

new_cars_1990s %>%
  mutate(predicted_mpg = prior_intercept + prior_slope * wt) %>%
  mutate(likelihood = dnorm(mpg, mean = predicted_mpg, sd = prior_sd_for_regression)) %>% 
  mutate(log_likelihood = log(likelihood)) %>%
  mutate(prior_for_slope_as_prob = dnorm(-5.6, mean = prior_slope, sd = prior_sd_for_slope)) %>%
  mutate(log_prior_for_slope_as_prob = log(prior_for_slope_as_prob)) %>%
  mutate(log_posterior_for_slope = log_likelihood + log_prior_for_slope_as_prob) %>%
  mutate(posterior_for_slope = exp(log_posterior_for_slope)) %>%
  summarize(median_log_posterior_for_slope = median(posterior_for_slope))
```

So far this output is giving me a number that is way off. In this case, I'm expecting `-5.6` but I'm getting a number close to zero.

```
median_log_posterior_for_slope
0.01645194
```

I'm not expecting to get the exact same number as `stan_glm()` because I'm assuming that what I'm doing is not the most advanced technique. I'm not trying to re-create whatever `stan_glm()` is doing under the hood. But I'm trying to develop some confidence that I understand what is happening here.

Is there a way to change this final section of code so I can accurately get a likelihood estimate for each point, given the parameters of the slope and intercept, and compare that to the distribution from my prior, to get the posterior, within one chunk of dplyr code? I know that practically speaking, this is in no man's land, but I'm doing this for learning!

---

As a final note, you could see that I'm putting the `sd` in for the `dnorm()` argument instead of the `mad`, because a normal distribution needs the mean and standard deviation. I find this from the `mad` using z-scores. Interesting that `stan_glm()` is using a normal distribution for the prior but reporting the statistics as `median` and `mad`.

```
median_value <- -5.3
mad_value <- 0.6

z_score_75 <- qnorm(0.75)

sigma_estimate <- mad_value / z_score_75

mean_estimate <- median_value

cat("Estimated Mean:", mean_estimate, "\n")
cat("Estimated Standard Deviation:", sigma_estimate, "\n")

Estimated Mean: -5.3 
Estimated Standard Deviation: 0.8895613
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this might be a Cross-validated question instead of SO.  The issue may be that likelihoods are often defined to contain arbitrary constant multipliers to make the expressions simple.  If two calculations use different constants, the likelihood values will be different.  What should be the same is the ratio of likelihoods at two parameter values, or the difference of log likelihoods.

Comment: Seem entirely reasonable that you would get a result close to zero if you set your prior to be equal to the parameters that you estimated from the data. It would be similar to using an offset in frequentist framework.